# $P$ and $A$ are $3 × 3$ real matrices such that $PAP^t = -A^t$

Tags: matrices

Let $P$ and $A$ be $3 × 3$ real matrices such that $PAP^t = -A^t$, where $P^t$ denotes the
transpose of $P$. Then find det$(P)$.

My approach: det$(PAP^t)$ = det$(P)$det$(A)$det$(P^t)$

det$(P)$=det$(P^t)$

So $[det$(P)$]^2=-1$

I don't know how this is possible.

Comment: The other option is $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I thought of that. But then how will I find det$(P)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is in fact, correct.
When you cancel $|A|$ on both sides in $|P||A||P|=-|A|$, you get $|P|^2=-1$ which is impossible of course, hence proving $|A|$ must be zero in order for the above equation to hold true. Thus $|P|$ may take any value.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find $\det(P)$ without additional assumptions. For instance, if $A=0$, then $PAP^T=-A^T$ for every $P$, but clearly there are $3\times3$ real matrices of positive, negative or zero determinants.